# replacing null values in column with a constant values in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I am trying to fill in the null values in a column (ADRPD) in a dataframe using the following code. But it does not work.

```
data$ADRPD[is.na(data$ADRPD)]= "medium"
```

This is the error:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(data$ADRPD), value = c(2L, 2L, 2L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Convert the column `ADRPD` to character and try again.

Comment: @ycw, thank you. How? I have two other characters: low and high.

Comment: `data$ADRPD <- as.character(data$ADRPD)`

Comment: First `data$ADRPD = factor(data$ADRPD, levels=c(levels(data$ADRPD), "medium"))`
Then, `data$ADRPD[is.na(data$ADRPD)]= "medium"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the missing data were saved as blank space rather than NA. First I converted the blank spaces to null values, then I changed to data to character as 'yaw' said. This is my code:

```
data = read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE, na.strings=c("","NA"))
data$ADRPD = as.character(data$ADRPD)
data$ADRPD[is.na(data$ADRPD)]= "medium"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. Use this as a reference:

```
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html
```

Alternatively:

```
for(i in 1:length(data$ADRPD)){
    if(is.na(data$ADRPD[[i]]) == true){
        data$ADRPD[[i]] <- c("some-constant")
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's syntax looks good to me. Care to elaborate why you think it's incorrect?

Comment: Yes, I have not seen this syntax before. I wrongly assumed it was incorrect. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.